# How do I test an automatically truncated text view?

Tags: python, android, appium, appium-android, python-appium

I have a container that holds a text view element. This text view element gets truncated automatically when it is long. In the UI, I can view it as truncated and it uses an ellipsis ("..."), but in Appium Inspector when you select the element it shows up as the whole text.

How do I test this text view element? I want to add a validation that the text element is only a maximum of three lines and it is truncated. I am also looking at other ways of validating this text element, maybe comparing height/width, but this is also problematic because there may be a change in the emulator being used and so the sizes may differ. Let me know your thoughts.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5SMw.jpg) is what the element looks like.